# C# with Excel Interop error format when i write data

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I have a c# software who use the excel-interop.

When I write the date I have this problem.

[image]

But in excel there is this result

[image]

Could you help me ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that both are formatted as dates and that it's sent as a date not a string. You can start by trying something like
xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1].NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy";

and instead of called .ToShortDateString() call .ToADate()

Comment: I have the same result with "-" unlike "/"    01-05-2016   :-(

Comment: Ah yes, then the problem might be with the fact that it's being sent as a string. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15604074/3383525 Also please note similar questions have been asked a few times, so this should probably be flagged as a duplicate.

Comment: @daniele3004 I've edited the answer, this might work better

Comment: Thank you..it's work for me