# Getting incorrect cell value while parsing excel with OpenXML

Tags: c#, openxml

I am trying to parse an excel and get the result in datatable using C# and openxml.
Below is my code snippet.

```
   value = cell.CellValue.InnerText;
if (cell.DataType != null && cell.DataType.Value == CellValues.SharedString)
        {
            return doc.WorkbookPart.SharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable.ChildElements.GetItem(int.Parse(value)).InnerText;
        }
        return value;
```

But if the cell value is **80.3600** then it is getting parsed as **80.36**.
Also if the value is **03-Jan-2018** then it is getting parsed as **43103**.
The problem is, the excel which I am trying to parse is dynamically generated and at run time I won't know which column is date and which column is numeric.
Is there any way to get the value as it is or get every value as a string i.e. no formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've noticed , numeric and date time cell's value have different styleIndex value.
you can get cell format by styleIndex from doc.WorkbookPart.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.NumberingFormats.

```
        var doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(File.Open("D:\\123.xlsx", FileMode.Open), false);
        var sheet = doc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().FirstOrDefault();
        WorksheetPart wsPart = (WorksheetPart)(doc.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(sheet.Id));
        var cells = wsPart.Worksheet.Descendants<Cell>().ToList();


        var numberingFormats = doc.WorkbookPart.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.NumberingFormats.ToList();

        var stringTable = doc.WorkbookPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>().FirstOrDefault();
        foreach (var cell in cells)
        {
            if (cell.DataType == null)
            {
                //DateTime 
                if (cell.StyleIndex != null)
                {
                    var numerFormat = numberingFormats.ElementAt((int) cell.StyleIndex.Value - 1) as NumberingFormat;
                    if (numerFormat.FormatCode.Value == "[$-409]mmmm\\ d\\,\\ yyyy;@")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.FromOADate(double.Parse(cell.InnerText)).ToString("MMMM dd,yyyy"));
                    }
                    else if (numerFormat.FormatCode.Value == "[$-409]dd\\-mmm\\-yy;@")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.FromOADate(double.Parse(cell.InnerText)).ToString("dd-MMM-yy"));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //Numeric
                    Console.WriteLine(int.Parse(cell.InnerText));
                }

            }
            else if (cell.DataType.Value == CellValues.SharedString)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(stringTable.SharedStringTable.ElementAt(int.Parse(cell.InnerText)).InnerText);
            }
        }
```

also can read this one:[Excel Interop cell formatting of Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15603098/excel-interop-cell-formatting-of-dates)

Comment: This only works if you have custom number format.  How do you get the value if it's one of the built in formats?